# SQL Subquery with Exists

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

I have a scenario that can be described with 3 tables; member, role and memberrole. Memberrole is the intersection of the the other two and I want to fully populate it with an outer join (from member and role). That is the easy part.

Now I want to be able to update the intersection for a new member or new role.

What I want to accomplish looks like this (but is incorrect syntax):

```
insert into memberrole (memberid,roleid)  
    select member.memberid, role.roleid 
    from member, role 
    where member.memberid, roleid not exists (select memberid, roleid 
                                              from memberrole)
```

...any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: either `where (member.memberid, roleid) not in (select ...)` or using a co-related subquery `where not exists (select ... where ...)`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into memberrole (memberid,roleid)
SELECT m.memberid, r.roleid
FROM member m
JOIN zrole r -- carthesian product MINUS the inner product
        ON NOT EXISTS (select *
        FROM memberrole mr
        WHERE mr.memberid = m.memberid
        AND mr.roleid = r.roleid
    );
```

---

Note: `role` is a reserved word. I replaced it by `zrole` .

Comment: Super, thanks so much joop. I have been away from code for a few years, just couldn't see through to the solution. Excellent!